# Nested SELECT Query Java + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, select, nested

I'm trying to get data from DB.

I must use to queries.

From the first query (In Loop) I get the code of Work `codew` and the I use it in the second query to get names.

Here's the code works without errors.

The first query fetch rows but the second is not executed.

```
int i=0;
c= new Connect().getCon();
try{

    java.sql.Statement st = c.createStatement();
    String sql= " SELECT  distinct(s.codew), title, nberstat, desc_w, dated,datef" +
                " FROM work w, employe e, stat s " +
                " WHERE w.codew=s.codew " +
                " and s.idemploye= e.idemploye " +
                " and stat_w=0 " +
                " and w.idcreator= 1";
     System.out.println(sql);       
    ResultSet res = (ResultSet) st.executeQuery(sql);
    String allW ="";
    while (res.next()) 
    {             
     String codew = res.getString("codew");  
     String title = res.getString("title");
     String desc_w = res.getString("desc_w");
     String dated = res.getString("dated");
     String date = res.getString("datef");
     int nberstat = res.getInt("nberstat"); String strnberstat = Integer.toString(nberstat);

    ///////////////////////////////////
        try
        {
            java.sql.Statement st2 = c.createStatement();
            q="SELECT distinct (name), lname From stat s, employe e WHERE codew LIKE '"+codew+"'";
            ResultSet res2 = (ResultSet) st2.executeQuery(q);
            while (res2.next()) 
            {
             String name = res.getString("name");
             String lname = res.getString("lname");
             allW = name + " "+lname+", "+allW;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {
            System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
        } 

     /////////////////////////////

........

}
c.close();
}
catch (SQLException s){
System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
}
```

I get this in the console for the second query! `SQL code does not execute.`
Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Ali

Comment: Try using this query `SELECT DISTINCT(name), lname from stat s,employe e WHERE s.codew  LIKE '"+codew+"'` or  `SELECT DISTINCT(name), lname from stat s,employe e WHERE e.codew  LIKE '"+codew+"'`

Comment: You have no idea which catch is printing since you're outputting the same message. And because you're catching it and not printing the exception ... you have no idea what the exception is. I would change your prints to tell you which it is, and add `s.getMessage()` to them which will tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should use [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with sql parameters "?" to prevent Sql injections.

Secondly, you are using the wrong statement in the second loop. You should be using `res2` not `res`.

This should be:

```
 String name = res2.getString("name"); //not res
 String lname = res2.getString("lname"); //not res
```

Thirdly, you should add a `finally{}` block and close your connection.